# No disabled JavaScript warning on new mobile version

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web, javascript

I was testing how a website worked without JS on my phone, and when I tried using SO, it just didn't work.

There is no "JavaScript is disabled" banner; the inbox, rep tab, voting buttons, etc. just fail silently.

Could a warning banner be added to the mobile version when JavaScript is disabled?

Comment: Will you ever remove notification about your absence? ;-)